# How to add keyboard shortcut to maximize a Java application from taskbar or quick launch?

Tags: java, swing, java-native-interface

I have a Java application. I want to add a feature to this that when the application is minimized, I press some key in keyboard and the application maximizes. How can I implement this feature through Java code?

Comment: if it requires native code, please tell me about how to do that in native way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either native code or hacking/misuse of the Java GUI implementation is required.

Natively in Linux (or other Unix/Unix-like system) with an XWindows display you need to register for keyboard events from the root window and all children and process those events.  You could open your own connection to the X display server just for the purpose of receiving keyboard events from the root window.

See the source code for "xev" for an example of registering a listener on an existing window such as the root window.  You'd need to modify that to just capture keyboard events.  I don't remember offhand how to get keypress events from all windows, though.  You either have to set listener attribute on the root windows to listen for key events from all children (if possible) or iterate over all windows and add your event listener attribute to each window while also registering for all window creation events so you can set your listener attribute on each new window as it's created.  See the source code for "xdpyinfo" for an example of how to iterate all windows.

You'd have to run a separate thread to run your XEvent listener, then when you detected your keyboard event, send an event back to your Java app to maximize your app.  So you'd need to know the window ID to send that event to.

A bit tedious, but not difficult to do.

And I suspect it's possible to hack/misuse the Java display classes to do the same from Java, but you're on your own there.

As for Windows-based systems?  I don't have experience coding GUIs for those so I can't help there.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I implement this feature through Java code?

You can't.  It would require native code to intercept keyboard events when the app. does not have focus.

Comment: if it requires native code, can you tell me about how to do that in native way...

Comment: I only know Java, so no, no I can't.  Note of course that it will be different (and probably different languages) for each OS.